# Should all 3rd-party jar dependencies be introduced to Maven via 'import' scope?

Tags: maven, maven-2

So confused about import scoping in Maven.  It seems to imply that all 3rd-party jar dependencies in a large, muti-module project would benefit from being dependency managed in the parent using the 'import' scope. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From maven's documentation about the `import` scope:

> This scope is only used on a dependency of type pom in the  section. It indicates that the specified POM should be replaced with the dependencies in that POM's  section. Since they are replaced, dependencies with a scope of import do not actually participate in limiting the transitivity of a dependency.

Frankly, this is usually isn't a very useful scope, and in any event it is not relevant for 3rd party `jar` dependencies - only for 3rd party `pom` dependencies. Where you place dependencies is somewhat a matter of taste, but the practice I found worked best for me was to place all the dependencies in the "lowest common denominator" pom's `<dependencyManagement>` section, and then referencing them in the `<dependencies>` section of the specific subprojects as needed.

Comment: I am a follower of the `don't repeat yourself' crowd and only use <depencencies>. But it is indeed a matter of taste and the import scope does not usualy add something

Comment: JBoss folks use it to bundle list of external and jboss deps in something they call "BOM", have a look at https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts - this IMHO illustrates that it _can_ be useful if used well

Comment: Indeed @PetrKozelka, it was [JBoss's Arquillian BOM (arquillian-bom)](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/?utm_source=cta) that is scoped to 'import' in the Mureinik recommended <dependencyManagement> section that got me thinking, inferring, and gasping for air in the fetid mysteries of Maven scoping. I breath free.